# What is [Application] in Mono for Android?

Tags: mono, xamarin.android

I'm new to mono and working through the Mono For Android tutorials. Can anyone point me to some documentation which explains the meaning of the [Application] tag above my classes?... Here's my issue:

I have come accross an issue where I have created two seperate classes App1.cs & App2.cs, both of these extend the Application Class (Public Class App1 : Application).. etc.

There is a tag above this declaration [Application] which seems to be causing deployment issues, although it builds fine.  If I comment one of these out, the application builds and deploys fine.

I have searched for info on these tags, but as yet cannot find anything in the search, FAQ's or on google... I guess the square brackes are causing me search problems.  Any help would be great...

Thanks

C

Comment: [Application] is a .Net "Attribute" it annotates the class so that it has a special meaning at runtime.

Comment: @IanNorton: In this case the annotation has compile-time meaning rather than runtime (see my answer for details)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Android applications you can subclass the [`Application`](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T:Android.App.Application) class in order to maintain global state in your app. An app can have at most one `Application` class, and it is shared throughout the app. In order to register your `Application` class it needs to be registered in [AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) (this applies to any Android component). Mono for Android uses attributes to generate the manifest during compilation, so any class decorated with [`ApplicationAttribute`](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T:Android.App.ApplicationAttribute) will generate configuration at build time.

Since only one `Application` class is allowed, this would explain the problems you are seeing when you try to register two of them. My guess (without having context into what you're trying to do here) is that you probably want to subclass [`Activity`](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T:Android.App.Activity) for these classes instead of `Application`.