# Bootstrapper for Android Application

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, monodevelop, xamarin.android

How to create a Bootstrapper for android Application.,

For instance, I want to override the Application Class of `Android.App.Application`, How to create a instance for that ?

And I want to Run an activity Based on certain Condition..

How can we do that.. using Mono for Android

Answer (score 1):

You must use the application tag in the androidmanifest.xml:

http://www.developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

See the android:name section.

There is probably an Attribute in mono for android, I will check. But this should work.

And here it is:

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/8697018/what-is-application-in-mono-for-android