# Monodroid putting parcelable objects to bundle

Tags: android, bundle, xamarin.android, parcelable

So I've been struggling with putting some values into a bundle in my overrided OnSaveInstanceState. I need so save some class objects on activity restart, meaning they have to be parcelable, which seem to be impossible to implement for Monodroid?

Source : http://docs.xamarin.com/android/about/limitations

What can i do to save these class objects in to the bundle without parcelable? I load data from a server, and I don't wish to do that again for example on a user rotation, which once again calls the OnCreate method. Therefore it would be nice to have them saved, which saves the server some pressure on occasional rotations and such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The originally accepted answer for this question, while true at the time it was answered, is no longer the case.

I had originally implemented the above suggestion and then later on through more searching found this:

http://dan.clarke.name/2012/09/implementing-iparcelable-in-mono-for-android/

The feature is now supported and the above link is a great resource on how to implement it.

Comment: Seems like there finally is support for Parcelable in Monodroid, this is now the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to implement the `IParcelable` interface in Mono for Android. Taken from [the docs](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/about/limitations):

> The IParcelable interface cannot be implemented at this time because
>   the android.os.Parcelable interface requires:
>
> - Classes implementing the Parcelable interface must also have a static    field called CREATOR, which is an object implementing the
>     Parcelable.Creator interface.
>
> Since mandroid.exe currently cannot generate fields, this interface
>   cannot be implemented. Support will be added in a future release.

Another approach you can take is to just store the object outside of the activity, such as in a class that subclasses [`Application`](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T:Android.App.Application). You can store data in your application class using either static properties, or you can access instance properties/methods on it by using the [`Application`](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=P:Android.App.Activity.Application) property from your activity. Some more details about using Application can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697018/what-is-application-in-mono-for-android).

Comment: I ended up using static variables for this case, thanks for the clearification

Comment: The docs have been updated, and supposedly there is now support for this ("This limitation applies to prior versions to 4.1 release. In 4.1 release, you can use ExportAttribute and ExportField attribute to generate Java methods and fields that can be named explicitly."). I'm going to give it a shot now and post any positive findings.

Comment: Xamarin's official example: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/ExportAttribute/ExportAttributeTest/MainActivity.cs